# Visual Studio Ripple emulator

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, ripple, tools-for-apache-cordova

I have a sample blank cordova project. When I run it on ripple emulator using Visual Studio 2015 the ripple emulator start on http://localhost:4400/index.html but window keeps on refreshing.

I have tried every possible solution reinstalled VS 2015, cordova, node.js and phonegap but couldn't fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with older version or try to in firefox. It is chrome version issue.